# Left join returns wrong total

Tags: sql, join, count, aggregate

I have two tables; `Calendar` and `Cases`. `Cases` has all the transaction data. This means if a transaction did not happen in a month, say June, there will be no row for June. However, if there are no transactions in June, I would want a row to be there saying `0` against June.

Here comes in `Calendar`, which has all the months I want to be in result set. However, regardless of left/right/outer join I apply, I am not being able to get those rows telling me there were `0` transactions in the table.

Below is the latest query I could come up with and also please find the result set. While the result set is showing the correct number of months, the total in the end is not right and is the same for each month. Where am I going wrong?

Please help!

**QUERY**

```
    SELECT cal.Org
      ,cal.CaseProduct
      ,cal.FaultGroup
      ,cal.ManufacturingMonth as ManufacturingMonth
      ,cal.ClosedMonth as ClosedMonth --ClosedMonthStart as ClosedMonth
      ,ISNULL(count(c.CaseProduct), 0) as TotalCases
FROM Calendar cal
LEFT JOIN [QualityForecasting].[dbo].[Cases] c
   ON cal.ManufacturingMonth = c.[ManufacturingDate]
  AND cal.CaseProduct = c.CaseProduct
  AND cal.FaultGroup = c.FaultGroup 
  AND c.CaseNature IN ('Missing / Damage Case', 'Compressor 2 Years Warranty', 'Compressor 3 Years Warranty', 'Showroom', 'Warehouse', 'Warranty (2-12 Months)', 'Within One Month Customer', 'From 31 to 90 Days Customer', 'From 91 to 120 Days Customer', 'Within 5~6 Months')
  AND c.CaseType IN ('Depot', 'Field', 'Direct', 'Field to Depot', 'Field to Mobile')
  AND c.LastTaskStatus NOT IN ('Transferred to Workshop', 'Mobile Required')
  AND SUBSTRING(c.CaseModelName, 1, 3) = 'DPL'
WHERE cal.ManufacturingMonth = '2012-08-01'
  AND cal.ClosedMonth <= '2014-01-01'  
  AND cal.Org = 'DPL'
  AND cal.FaultGroup = 'COMPRESSOR'
GROUP BY cal.Org
        ,cal.CaseProduct
        ,cal.FaultGroup
        ,cal.ManufacturingMonth 
        ,cal.ClosedMonth;
```

**RESULT SET**

```
Org CaseProduct FaultGroup  ManufacturingMonth  ClosedMonth TotalCases
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2012-08-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2012-09-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2012-10-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2012-11-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2012-12-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-01-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-02-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-03-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-04-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-05-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-06-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-07-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-08-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-09-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-10-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-11-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2013-12-01  65
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-08-01  2014-01-01  65
```

**UPDATE 1**

Cases Table Structure:

```
CaseNumber  CaseProduct ManufacturingDate   FaultGroup
15-04-555333    REF 2012-10-01  GAS CHARGING                                      
14-11-513482    REF 2012-10-01  EVAPORATOR                                        
15-04-556248    REF 2012-10-01  GASKET                                            
15-04-564243    REF 2012-10-01  COMPRESSOR                                        
15-06-599612    REF 2012-10-01  WIRING - PRODUCT
```

Calendar Table Structure

```
Org CaseProduct FaultGroup  ManufacturingMonth  ClosedMonth
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-07-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-08-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-09-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-10-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-11-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2012-12-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2013-01-01
DPL REF COMPRESSOR  2012-07-01  2013-02-01
```

Comment: You placed the conditions completely wrong :-) You need to move the conditions on `cal` to WHERE and those on `c` to `ON`. The basic rule is *conditions on the inner table in `ON`, those on the outer table in `WHERE`*

Comment: Done, no use. still the same result set Making the suggested changes in question's query too.

Comment: Its not, it returns the same result set.

Comment: The title says LEFT JOIN, but the code has a RIGHT JOIN... Since you mainy select cal columns, I suggest you put that table first and do a left join. (Most people find left join easier to understand...)

Comment: You edited your query, but also resulting in an inner join. Btw, it's still not what Y.B. wrote.

Comment: My bad, i made the wrong update. I have changed it now. But the result set is the same.

Comment: If it's the same result despite running a logically different query it' based on your actual data.

Comment: Run the query without the `COUNT` (use `c.*`instead) and check the actual rows returned.

Comment: OK, I think we need a look at the source data. Can you please add a sample from each table?

Comment: @Y.B. i have added the sample data in my question. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

This is the case for `LEFT JOIN`. It is best to leave only joining conditions in    `ON` clause, so this should work:

```
SELECT cal.Org
      ,cal.CaseProduct
      ,cal.FaultGroup
      ,cal.ManufacturingMonth as ManufacturingMonth
      ,cal.ClosedMonth as ClosedMonth --ClosedMonthStart as ClosedMonth
      ,ISNULL(count(c.CaseProduct), 0) as TotalCases
FROM Calendar cal
LEFT JOIN [QualityForecasting].[dbo].[Cases] c
   ON cal.ManufacturingMonth = c.[ManufacturingDate]
  AND cal.CaseProduct = c.CaseProduct
  AND cal.FaultGroup = c.FaultGroup 
  AND c.CaseNature IN ('Missing / Damage Case', 'Compressor 2 Years Warranty', 'Compressor 3 Years Warranty', 'Showroom', 'Warehouse', 'Warranty (2-12 Months)', 'Within One Month Customer', 'From 31 to 90 Days Customer', 'From 91 to 120 Days Customer', 'Within 5~6 Months')
  AND c.CaseType IN ('Depot', 'Field', 'Direct', 'Field to Depot', 'Field to Mobile')
  AND c.LastTaskStatus NOT IN ('Transferred to Workshop', 'Mobile Required')
  AND SUBSTRING(c.CaseModelName, 1, 3) = 'DPL'
WHERE cal.ManufacturingMonth = '2012-08-01'
  AND cal.ClosedMonth <= '2014-01-01'  
  AND cal.Org = 'DPL'
  AND cal.FaultGroup = 'COMPRESSOR'
GROUP BY cal.Org
        ,cal.CaseProduct
        ,cal.FaultGroup
        ,cal.ManufacturingMonth 
        ,cal.ClosedMonth;
```

**UPD 1** This should have worked. The following is a desperate attempt to try anything else at all:

```
SELECT cal.Org
      ,cal.CaseProduct
      ,cal.FaultGroup
      ,cal.ManufacturingMonth
      ,cal.ClosedMonth
      ,(SELECT count(*)
        FROM [QualityForecasting].[dbo].[Cases] c
        WHERE cal.ManufacturingMonth = c.[ManufacturingDate]
          AND cal.CaseProduct = c.CaseProduct
          AND cal.FaultGroup = c.FaultGroup 
          AND c.CaseNature IN ('Missing / Damage Case', 'Compressor 2 Years Warranty', 'Compressor 3 Years Warranty', 'Showroom', 'Warehouse', 'Warranty (2-12 Months)', 'Within One Month Customer', 'From 31 to 90 Days Customer', 'From 91 to 120 Days Customer', 'Within 5~6 Months')
          AND c.CaseType IN ('Depot', 'Field', 'Direct', 'Field to Depot', 'Field to Mobile')
          AND c.LastTaskStatus NOT IN ('Transferred to Workshop', 'Mobile Required')
          AND SUBSTRING(c.CaseModelName, 1, 3) = 'DPL'
       ) as TotalCases
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
         Org
        ,CaseProduct
        ,FaultGroup
        ,ManufacturingMonth
        ,ClosedMonth
      FROM Calendar
      WHERE ManufacturingMonth = '2012-08-01'
        AND ClosedMonth <= '2014-01-01'  
        AND Org = 'DPL'
        AND FaultGroup = 'COMPRESSOR'
     ) cal
```

**UPD 2** Since "desperate attempt" produced the same results it's time to run the subquery with individual combinations of parameters and see what is going on with the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM [QualityForecasting].[dbo].[Cases] c
WHERE cal.ManufacturingMonth = /* particular c.ManufacturingDate */
  AND cal.CaseProduct =        /* particular c.CaseProduct       */
  AND cal.FaultGroup =         /* particular c.FaultGroup        */
  AND c.CaseNature IN ('Missing / Damage Case', 'Compressor 2 Years Warranty', 'Compressor 3 Years Warranty', 'Showroom', 'Warehouse', 'Warranty (2-12 Months)', 'Within One Month Customer', 'From 31 to 90 Days Customer', 'From 91 to 120 Days Customer', 'Within 5~6 Months')
  AND c.CaseType IN ('Depot', 'Field', 'Direct', 'Field to Depot', 'Field to Mobile')
  AND c.LastTaskStatus NOT IN ('Transferred to Workshop', 'Mobile Required')
  AND SUBSTRING(c.CaseModelName, 1, 3) = 'DPL'
```

Comment: should have been a comment

Comment: @sagi Sorry, accidentally submitted incomplete.

Comment: Nopes, returns 65 against each row.

Comment: may be need to add checking CaseNumber is null or not

Comment: @Salik Is `[CaseNumber]` a column of `[Cases]`? Try the updated version.

Comment: yes, `[CaseNumber]` is a column of `[Cases]`. Still gives the same result.

Comment: @daniel : can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Salik Well it seems you do have 65 cases each month after all. :-) Can you please verify `cal.ManufacturingMonth = c.[ManufacturingDate]` is valid? I mean, `c.[ManufacturingDate]` store month.

Comment: ,sum(case when c.CaseNumberis not null then 1 else 0 end) as TotalCases

Comment: @daniel: `NULL` is ignored by every aggregate function, so `COUNT(NULL)` returns `0`

Comment: @Y.B. yes, the column is valid and so is the join. and no, there aren't 65 cases each month :)

Comment: then, seems there is no linkage on **ClosedMonth** between two join tables

Comment: there is no linkage except that the values of both columns will match.

Comment: I am doubt that the case table should have a date column to work with the calendar close month. Otherwise, all the cases will join to all calendar month results same count.

Comment: @daniel Ah, you think `Cases` has `ClosedMonth` column as well?

Comment: I think there should have a column like CaseDate in Cases, then filter of CaseDate and close Month in the join-on-clause. Or more simple if exact ClosedMonth in Cases.

Comment: @daniel CloseMonth need not to have a linkage. The common date values will be in Calendar.ManufacturingMonth and Cases.ManufacturingDate

Comment: i guess I am not yet that desperate to go with sub-queries :p

Comment: btw, it returns the same result set. Makes me wonder what the hell is wrong!?

Comment: @Salik Well, you do have 65 cases each month after all. :-)

Comment: @Salik Must be some case of NULL or very odd database-wide setting affecting string and date comparison.